# validators.Regex in Form Python Flask doesn't work

Tags: python, regex, forms, flask

Currently my program is not accepting any form of regex strings I give my validators. This is the code Im running and it returns me invalid input as a result.

```
TextField('Number',[validators.Regexp(regex=r'^[0-9]')])
```

Doesn't matter if I supply numbers, letters, combination it keeps returning me with Invalid input. Any ideas?

Comment: What are you expecting to match with your regex?

Comment: My end goal is to match it towards IP addresses, but for troubleshooting Im just looking to match it towards numbers as of this moment.

Comment: You can match an IP adress with [`^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$`](https://regex101.com/r/3fnniI/1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

^[0-9] means that your string must start with ONE number from 0-9 exactly. If you want a more complex number validation check out [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html).

Also I suggest using [RegExr](http://regexr.com/) in order to check your regular expressions.